# If I don't distribute my app through the App Store, how can I register the app scheme for deep links?

Tags: ios, app-store, deep-linking, url-scheme

Can I enable links and deep links to an app that is not distributed with the App Store?

From what I understand, the URL scheme is stored in the app plist and then used to link to the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiled application can handle URL schemes, regardless its presence on the App Store. The settings listed in the .plist file are independent from the distribution method.

Comment: All right. Thanks. So there is not a centralised list of schemes. I guess in case of name conflict, with 2 apps with same URL scheme, one of the two is picked?

Comment: The firstly installed app gets the priority in that case.